# How to make a partial view configurable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, renderpartial, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Let's say I have a partial view named 'Container' which contains two partial views called 'PartialA' and 'PartialB'. On the 'Conatiner' partial view I want some sort of configurational ability so that when we use the 'Container' partial view on the main view we can control the visibility of inner views, i.e. whether both PartialA and PartialB should be rendered or just render  any of them or none of them at all. Basically I want main view to decide which inner views should be rendered.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Use the view data or pass the view a model that specifies visibility.

Comment: Agree about the view model (reflected in response below),  disagree with view data. Although it will work, its like declaring global variable in object oriented application. Really bad design IMHO, but of course, both global variable and view data will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a view model that you will pass to Container that will include 1 flags (or add to existing one):

   ```
   public bool PartialAVisible;
   public bool PartialBVisible;
   ```
2. Set the visibility flags as you wish the visibility to be in the Controller that will call your main view or inside the main view and pass it over to Container
3. In the Container perform the following logic

   ```
   if (PartialAVisible)
      @Html.Partial("PartialA", model)
   if (PartialBVisible)
      @Html.Partial("PartialB", model)
   ```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage add your rules there if you are going to need this through out your application.

```
public class ViewPageBase : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
{
    public bool PartialAVisable
    { 
        get
        {
            //Determin if visable
        }

    }

    public bool PartialBVisable
    { 
        get
        {
            //Determin if visable
        }

    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (PartialAVisable)
        {
            //Apend partail A
        }

        if (PartialBVisable)
        {
            //Apend partail B
        }

        base.Render(writer);
    }
}
```